# Unable to insert into subdocument

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have the following schema

```
var ChildSchema = new Schema({
    name: String,
    value: String
});

var ParentSchema = new Schema({
    children: [ChildSchema]
});
```

Now, I wish to insert entries into parent.children.

I did the following:

```
parentRecord.children.push({
    name:"foo",
    value: "bar"
});
```

When I use a console.log, I can see here that the record has been successfully added into the parent record's children property. It also has been give an ID.

Now, I attempt to save the record:

```
parentRecord.save(myCallback);
```

While the save is a success, I see that the entry was not added into the children property.

1. I even tried to use `parentRecord.markModified("children");` but that also does not help
2. I have also ensured that I declare the `ChildSchema` before I declare the `ParentSchema`.

I am at my wits end trying to figure out what's wrong. I have set the debug property of mongoose to true. I can see that it's identifying the new entry but I just can't see it getting saved in my database.

Following is the output from the debug messages:

```
Mongoose: parentRecord.update({ _id: ObjectId("5551895182d9adbe1da34d6a") }) { '$inc': { __v: 1 }, '$set': { anotherField: 'anotherValue' }, '$pushAll': { fields: [ { _id: ObjectId("55518c682a0744dc20f1473b"), value: 'bar', name: 'foo' } ] } } {}
```

Any hints on what else I need to do to get the entry to save?

I am using mongoose 3.8.12

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell by the change log it looks like this was an issue that was resolved in version 3.8.13. You may want to try upgrading.

https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/2082